# Permission denied for a css when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, compass-sass

I have a sample app that is using `compass` gem including blueprint. I just deployed this app on heroku for the first time and I'm seeing the following error in heroku logs

> Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/public/stylesheets/ie.css):

Is there something special required in my rails app that will make this error go away? I'm assuming it's coming because I'm using the compass gem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a `compass compile` before deploying to heroku.

Also, in your production.rb, add the following line:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:never_update] = true
```

This will prevent compass from compiling css at runtime (since heroku does not allow writes on filesystem)

Answer (score 1):

Just set this option to `true` in `config/environments/production.rb` and everything will work fine:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Save `ie.css` from your local machine, add it into your public/stylesheets folder, and push it up to heroku.